# How can I map array with objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Hi I am trying to fill object which make by the interface:

```
export interface MainInfo {
    speaks: Array<Object>
}
```

and then in component I fill it like this:

```
import { MainInfo } from '../../interfaces/Interface';

export const UserCard: React.FC = () => {
let mainInfo: MainInfo = {
    speaks:  [
      {
        "language": "Ukrainian",
        "level": "Native"
      },
      {
        "language": "Russian",
        "level": "Fluent"
      }
    ]
  }
return(
<>
 {mainInfo.speaks.map((speaksInfo, id) => {
     return (
        <div className="languages" key={id}>
           <p>{speaksInfo.language}</p>
           <p>{speaksInfo.level}</p>
        </div>
     );
 })}
</>
);
};
```

but array dosn't map and I have error

```
Property 'level' does not exist on type 'Object'.  TS2339
   <p>{speaksInfo.level}</p>
                  ^
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Provide a better type for the speaks property?

Comment: What @jonrsharpe said. It's true that `level` does not exist on type `Object`. `level` does, however, exist on type `{level:string, language:string}`, for example. I would make your interface have `speaks: {level:string,language:string}[]` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try with a better typing of MainInfo like this:

```
export interface MainInfo {
    speaks: {
        language: string;
        level: string;
    }[]
}
```